# Enable Notification/Indication BLE (ua-651) GATTTOOL

Tags: bash, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to get Blood Presure datas from the UA-651-BLE from A&D.

Firstly, before developping a C++ Application with Qt, I'm trying to do this work thanks to Gatttool.
The device is pair, I can connect my computer in aim to read values.

But if I think good, to read blood presure datas, I need to allow indications & notifications.
How can I do that ?

Thanks a lot for your replies, I really need help !

Comment: Set the CCC value to 0x2.

Comment: Tanks for your replie, but how? I try a lot Of things.

Comment: `gatttool -b <mac_address> -I` to start the tool in interactive mode. Then `connect` from the prompt to connect to the device. Then `char-write-req <CCC handle> 02`.

Comment: I try your solution, but I can't write on CCC handle. In the device's documentation, attribute has no flag (READ, WRITE, INDICATE). Anyway I try, but the reponse is : `Error: Characteristic Write Request failed: Attribute value length is invalid`.

EdIT : I can write 0000 on this handle, but no 0001 or 0002

Comment: I don't have the full specs of your device so I can't really comment more than the general advice already given.

Comment: You help me a lot and now it works ! Thank's a lot !

Comment: Glad to hear it. I suggest you write an answer to your own question and then mark that answer as accepted. It may help others in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank's to Kaylum, I'm now able to read what I want :

```
gatttool -b <mac_address> -I //to start the tool in interactive mode. Then connect from the prompt to connect to the device. Then 
char-write-req <CCC handle> 02
```